# Outsourcing TableView protocols

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to outsource the delegate and datasource protocol of a tableView.
So i created a new `TableViewController`, made a `Cocoa Touch Class` for it
and removed the existing delegate and data source connection in the storyboard. Finally i set the delegate and datasource programmatically.
It works fine so far but i have a question.
First look at my code, please.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let protocols = TableViewProtocols()

        tableView.delegate = protocols
        tableView.dataSource = protocols
    }
}
```

As I said it works fine but i tried to make it easier and that does not work

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = TableViewProtocols()
        tableView.dataSource = TableViewProtocols()
    }
}
```

In the first example I created an object of `TableViewProtocols` and saved it in `protocols`. I assigned it to the delegate and datasource. That is working.

In the second example i didn't save an instance of `TableViewProtocols`. Instead i did creation and assigning in one step in a single line.
And that does not work. and i don't know why. Because for me it looks the same. What is the difference in first create an object and creation and assigning directly in a single line?

Any advice is appropriated.
Thank you.

Comment: The second one does not work because it creates two separate instances of `TableViewProtocols`. As a guess, the delegate and data source interact with one another (depend on each other) in such a way that they must be in the same instance.

Comment: Ah ok, yes i think you are right. That makes sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Table Views don't maintain strong references to their delegate or data source objects. So when you are setting them directly and the call goes out of scope, the objects are deleted and the the tableview doesn't have a delegate or a data source anymore.

It's perfectly acceptable to have different data sources and delegates, even using a table view controller. A simple way to do this is to have the table view controller have a reference to the object that you want to delegate to and that it has strong references to, and then to set the delegate and the datasource in view did load:

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var protocols = TableViewProtocols() // Not the best name, but it's what you have.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = protocols
    tableView.dataSource = protocols
}
```

}